# How do I get styled attributes from xml layout parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having huge troubles getting custom layout attributes from the parent element of an xml layout
Ok suppose I have a layout like so

```
<com.blackstephen.customlayoutexperimental.StripedLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/stripedLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:divider_width="5dp">

<!-- put first view to left. -->
<TextView
    android:background="@mipmap/o"
    android:paddingStart="6dp"
    android:paddingEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_position="left"
    app:percentage="40"
    android:text="@string/l1"/>
<com.blackstephen.customlayoutexperimental.StripedLayout/>
```

Note that I have these styled attributes in the child (TextView) app:layout_position="left"
        app:percentage="40"
and I can get these values by placing this inner class into the code for the custom display

```
 /**
 * Custom per-child layout information.
 */
public static class LayoutParams extends MarginLayoutParams {
    /**
     * The gravity to apply with the View to which these layout parameters
     * are associated.
     */
    public int gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
    public int position = 0;
    public int percentage = 33;

    public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);

        // Pull the layout param values from the layout XML during
        // inflation.  This is not needed if you don't care about
        // changing the layout behavior in XML.
        TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.StripedLayoutLP);
        gravity = a.getInt(R.styleable.StripedLayoutLP_android_layout_gravity, gravity);
        position = a.getInt(R.styleable.StripedLayoutLP_layout_position, position);
        percentage = a.getInt(R.styleable.StripedLayoutLP_percentage, percentage);
        a.recycle();
    }
```

But this will only give me the styled attributes in each child
I also want the styled attribute from the parent called app:divider_width="5dp".
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a XML file in your drawable folder and place all the attribute which you want in that XML. If you want a divider create a `divider.xml` in drawable and define all the attributes you want. then user `android:divider"@drawable/divider"` to call those attribute on the TextView.

EXAMPLE:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" /> // color of the divider
```

In the TextView use

```
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
```

Comment: but I would like to create  a library project to make my layout more re-usable so I need everything abstracted out

Comment: To make it a part of your library u need to make a theme. Did my solution work for your problem? If yes please mark it as  correct for other people to refer

Answer (score 0):

For each child I get the layout params using 
an inner class named LayoutParams which extends MarginLayoutParams

But for the parent layout params I use this code in the constructor

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.StripedLayout);
    dividerWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.StripedLayout_divider_width, dividerWidth);
    mDividerWidth = dividerWidth;
    a.recycle();
```